# Numbers that are the sum of the cubes of their digits

Tags: mathematics, no-computers

There  are  just  four 3-digit numbers which are the sums of the cubes of their digits. For example:

$370 = 3^3 + 7^3 + 0^3$ and $371 = 3^3 + 7^3 + 1^3$.

Without using a calculator/computer, can you find the other two 3-digit numbers with this property? Are there any more such numbers?

Comment: [Spoilers: answer inside](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635694/sum-of-cubes-of-the-digits-of-a-number-equal-to-to-the-number). I’m pretty sure the first part of the answer has to be done by exhaustion. The second part is an actually interesting problem, though

Comment: See also OEIS: [A005188](https://oeis.org/A005188)

Comment: By a difficult and exhaustive search, I've found two more numbers that are the sum of the cubes of their digits: $0, 1$.

Answer (score 8):

Partial Answer

> We are finding digits $a,b,c$ such that $100a+10b+c=a^3+b^3+c^3$. Taking $\pmod 9$, we have $$\big(a^3-a\big)+\big(b^3-b\big)+\big(c^3-c\big)\equiv0\pmod9$$
> These are the values of remainder of $a^3-a$ divided by $9$:

```
a(mod 9)|a^3-a(mod 9)
0       |0
1       |0
2       |6
3       |6
4       |6
5       |3
6       |3
7       |3
8       |0
```

So

> The $3$ digit numbers that satisfy the condition are either all digits from either groups $(0,1,8,9), (2,3,4), (5,6,7)$ or one digit per group.

Comment: Now it reduces to 42 possibilities, which can be easily bruteforced by hand.

Answer (score 7):

I happen to *know* them. Does that count as a valid answer? When I was young, we 'discovered' that repeatedly applying the procedure $abc \to a^3 + b^3 + c^3$ always ended up at one of four numbers; 370, 371,

> $153 = 1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3$ or $407 = 4^3 + 0^3 + 7^3$.

For me, it's hard to forget, just like [this anecdote about Hardy visiting Ramanujan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1729_(number)):

> I remember once going to see him when he was ill at Putney. I had ridden in taxi cab number 1729 and remarked that the number seemed to me rather a dull one, and that I hoped it was not an unfavourable omen. "No," he replied, "it is a very interesting number; it is the smallest number expressible as the sum of two cubes in two different ways."

($1729 = 1^3 + 12^3 = 9^3 + 10^3$)

Comment: Haha well that works too, if you already know the answer :)

Comment: That is one of my favorite maths stories, along with Gauss summing 1+2+...+100 in a few seconds in class. I am not entirely sure that the events actually took place, but they certainly make great stories.

Comment: Somebody needs to find that taxi cab (or at least the number sign from the top of it) and install it in a mathematics-themed museum somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

To show there is no four digit solution, the maximum sum of the cubes of the digits of a four digit number is $4\cdot 9^3=2912$  For a number less than this, the maximum sum of the cubes of the digits is $1+3\cdot 9^3=2188$.  The thousands digit must be $1$.  To get the sum of cubes up to $1000$ we need a $9$, two $8$s, one $8$ plus two $7$s, or three $7$s.  We can check that $1,7,7,7$ and $1,7,7,8$ fail.  With two $8$s we have $1^3+2\cdot 8^3=1025$ and all the possibilities fail.  Then $1^3+9^3=730$  We need another digit to be at least $4$ to get up to $1000$.  This is in the range of hand check as well and nothing works.

Comment: `The thousands digit must be 1.` Why?

Comment: Because the sum of the cubes is less than 2188 at that point and no number with a thousands digit of $2$ matches its sum of cubes because the lower digits cannot contribute enough.

Answer (score 4):

There are

- two 1-digit solutions: $0,1$
- no 2-digit solutions: $5$ and above have 3-digit cubes. A digit of $4$ would require the number to have another digit of $6$ or above. The 12 possibilities with digits $\le 3$ are easily eliminated.
- four 3-digit solutions, as indicated in the question.
- no 4-digit solutions, as Ross Millikan has proved.
- no higher-digit solutions, as for $n > 4, n \times 9^3$ has fewer than $n$ digits.

So there are six numbers total that are the sum of the cubes of their digits.